# Activate Angular guard for both parent and child nested module routes

Tags: angular, nested-routes, angular-router-guards, angular-guards

I'm working with Nested Module Structure and having some difficulty to implement guard.

Right Now I have to use `canActivate` on parent module route and `canActivateChild` on every child module route.
**I want a solution where I will just put guard on Parent module route and that guard will also be activated on all the child module routes...**

**Following is the module structure**

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
{
    path: 'pages',
    loadChildren: () => PagesModule,
  },
```

**pages-routing.module.ts  `canActivate` on `AdminModule` route.**

```
{
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: () => AdminModule,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
```

**admin-routing.module.ts  `canActivateChild` on every child module of admin**

```
{
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => DashboardModule,
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'allusers',
    loadChildren: () => AllUsersModule,
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
  },
```

**dashboard-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: DashboardComponent }];
```

**allusers-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: AllUsersComponent }];
```

**AuthGaurd**

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    private readonly route: Router,
  ) {}

  async canActivate() {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedOut()) {
      localStorage.clear();
      this.route.navigate(['/login']);
      alert('Access Denied Token Not Found');
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  canActivateChild(
    childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ):
    | boolean
    | UrlTree
    | Observable<boolean | UrlTree>
    | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
    return this.canActivate();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't state this explicitly, but I'm going to assume that you want `AuthGuard` to execute on every child route of `admin/` (in your example, these will be `pages/admin/dashboard` and `pages/admin/allusers`).

In this case, it seems that you confused `canActivate` with `canActivateChild`.

If you define pages-routing.module.ts like so:

```
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: () => AdminModule,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],      // fire for pages/admin page itself
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard], // fire for every descendant
  },
```

then all routes that are descendants of `pages/admin/` URL will fire AuthGuard on entry, every time navigation occurs into or within `pages/admin/` URL tree. You don't need to add any `canActivate` or `canActivateChild` anywhere else in the routing configuration. Note that going to `pages` itself will not trigger `AuthGuard`.

Edit: added `canActivate` entry, too, since you wrote you want to guard `pages/admin` itself as well.

More generally, `canActivateChild`, when defined on route `X/`, will fire every time navigation occurs whose target is a descendant of route `X/`, but not route `X` itself.

Comment: I'm sorry If I didn't post an understandable question. But I don't want for every child of `pages`. I want for every child of `admin`

Comment: Including admin itself?

Comment: yes including `admin`. Although `pages` is parent. But I'm keeping `admin page` as parent in this particular case.

Comment: OK, I adjusted my answer.

Comment: `4200/admin` works. But `4200/dashboard` and `4200/allusers` are visible. guard is not working on them

Comment: Wait, what's your routing structure? It isn't hierarchical? How are the three routing modules connected?

Comment: The routing structure is in my question. Below the `Following is the module structure`.

Comment: `Pages Module` is imported in `App Module`. There are multiple pages including `admin` in `Pages Module`, and all those modules are `imported` in `Pages Module`. Then `Admin Module` is imported in `Pages Module`. And `Dashboard Module` and `Allusers Module` are imported in `Admin Module.`

Comment: `Dashboard and Allusers` are childeren of `Admin`. Admin is child of `Pages`. And Pages is imported in `App`.

Comment: If dashboard and allusers are children of admin, which is a child of pages, wouldn't that mean that the URL for allusers is actually 4200/pages/admin/allusers?

Comment: Yes you are right. But I have multiple child modules in pages. And I don't want to activate that guard on every child module. Instead I want to activate that guard for `Admin Module` and  `Admin's Child Modules`. Let's say I have 5 modules in `pages module`. If I put guard on `pages` it will be activated on all those 5 `child modules of pages module`. And I don't want that. I want only `Admin and Admin's child` under `guard`, not other `Admin Siblings` as well.